# String to array in JS

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I am grabbing an array from a p tag and it works absolutely fine, but I am unable to use it as an array.

```
var leaderboard = [];
leaderboard = $(".tojs").text();
console.log(leaderboard);
```

Output (as intended):

```
[["aname1",1,649,201],["aname2",2,362,171],["aname3",3,270,234],["aname4",4,233,60],["aname5",5,211,9],["aname6",6,186,101],["aname7",7,157,41]]
```

But the problem occurs when I try to call a value.

```
leaderboard[0][0]
```

Output:

```
[
```

---

How would I be able to read an array from a p tag?

Comment: If it's valid JSON then use `JSON.parse` on it to turn it into an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output you get from `console.log` is a string, not an array. Try using `JSON.parse()` on it before trying to access like Sergiu suggested in his comment.

```
var leaderboard = [];
leaderboard = JSON.parse($(".tojs").text());
console.log(leaderboard[0][0]); //should be "aname1"
```

Comment: **Note:** [`jQuery.parseJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/) - *"Where the browser provides a native implementation of JSON.parse, jQuery uses it to parse the string."* This is a suitable replacement if you are already using jQuery in the case where `JSON.parse` does not exist in a browser.